# The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous when calling classifier_model.fit

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tensorflow

I'm calling the classifier_model.fit function as follows:

```
history = classifier_model.fit(x=train_data,
                               validation_data=val_data,
                               epochs=epochs)
```

Which gives me the following error `The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

The csv being read in looks like the following:

| clean_text | sentiment |
| --- | --- |
| really enjoyed the movie | positive |

I'm struggling to really understand what the error is telling me, from what I've read this error usually occurs when using if/or/and statements which I don't believe I'm calling here.

Anyone able to give me a better insight than the IDE?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Full error stack

```
Training model with https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/small_bert/bert_en_uncased_L-4_H-512_A-8/1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-922d461884ba> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 print(f'Training model with {tfhub_handle_encoder}')
----> 2 history = classifier_model.fit(x=train_data,
      3                                validation_data=val_data,
      4                                epochs=epochs)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1525     @final
   1526     def __nonzero__(self) -> NoReturn:
-> 1527         raise ValueError(
   1528             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1529             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Line of code it fails on:

```
print(f'Training model with {tfhub_handle_encoder}')
history = classifier_model.fit(x=train_data,
                               validation_data=val_data,
                               epochs=epochs)
```

Comment: You will need to add a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here. Also give the full error stack

Comment: Just added them both

Comment: What is `epochs`?  Is it a simple integer?  What's the shape of `train_data` and `val_data`?

Comment: Epoch = 5, train data  is (534, 2), val_data is (35, 2)

Comment: What I don't understand is I'm not doing any comparassdons, so I don't know what would return ambiguity?

Comment: To diagnose the problem please provide the data processing pipeline, like, how are `train_data` and `val_data` created? Where were they loaded from? In particular, I don't think `model.fit()` supports pandas DataFrame now (see [docs](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/#:~:text=%5Bsource%5D-,fit%20method,-Model.fit)).